# Doctrine inheritance or just association in this case?

Tags: class, oop, doctrine-orm, relationship, symfony

I am stuck at this question where I am turning my Class Diagram into symfony code. I have a Project class and a ProjectType class. Normally you would say a project IS of a certain project type so that would imply inheritance (IS A) relationship. Now doctrine states about inheritance:

> A mapped superclass is an abstract or concrete class that provides
>   persistent entity state and mapping information for its subclasses,
>   but which is not itself an entity.

The idea is that different project types can be made (they should be manageable). If doctrine says in this example that ProjectType is not an entity then I can't instantiate them. So I thought of a OneToMany assocation. Is this correct OOP?

Comment: I suspect you may be confusing IS A with HAS A.

Comment: That was my first confusion, but a project has 1 and only 1 type. Let's say a project type = symfony. Then you would say 'this project IS a symfony project'

Comment: Lets suppose the project includes some sort of calendar perhaps.  Would you then say "this project is a calendar"?  In other words, a project is not a project type.

Comment: Yes, but then it sounds logical to say the project has a calender. Somehow it doesn't sound logical to me to say project has a project type but more like project is of a certain type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the relation between entities in an abstract class, If the relationship changes in the concrete entity you can overwrite it.

For example you have an abstract class called Project, that has a many to on relationship with ProjectType.

Then you create two entities extending from Project called GreenProject and RedProject. GreenProject only can have one ProjectType associated so the relationship defined in the base class is ok.

Them RedProject can have more than one ProjectType so is a ManyToMany relationship. Then you have to overwrite the existing relationship in the base class by redeclaring the $projectType property in the RedProject class and using the apropiate annotations.

You can distribute your superclases within a bundle for instance, and the use them extending them in your AppBundle. This is usedby FosUserBundle (User class), FosOauthBundle (Client and Token classes for instance) and others.

Comment: I see what you mean, but wouldn't a DesignProject or DevProject not already be a project type itself? Then it would mean everytime I want to create a  new type I need to create a whole new class.

Comment: May be the names where not the best ones for the examples. I changed DesignProject by RedProject and DevProject by GreenProject, and may be now  is easier to understand.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that if I have 100 project types that are different I need to make 100 entities?

Comment: No. If you 100 project types create the ProjectType entity and populate the database with the 100 project types. The inheritance for entities is used when you want to distribute your entities or when some of your entities shares many features.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in this case a project can always only have 1 type, so cant the Project class not have a direct link to the ProjectType class?

Comment: The exposed example was focused on the class inheritance used to define Doctrine Entities. If you are not going to redistribute your classes or you don't have entities that shares features, you don't need to create an abstract class and extend for it to create entities.

Comment: So in this case an association would be acceptable OOP design?

Comment: It has nothing to do with OOP, this is business logic. You are relating entities because your business logic requires it. This relationship is a foreign key in a database, not an inheritance relationship. Is like an entity relationship diagram and a class diagram, looks similar but they are in "different planes".